# CSS inline-block li's too long text breaks alignment of list items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is how my list looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/6mcLfdjj/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="content" class="row">
        <div id="form-container" class="col-md-12">
            <div id="request-types-list">
                <ul class="request-list-main">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">xxxasa</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">xxxasaxxxasaxxxasaxxxasaxxxasxxxxxxxx</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">x</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">xxxasaxxxasaxxxasaasdasdadadasdasdsadasdsaasddasasd</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">x</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">x</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.request-list-main {
  list-style-type: none;
}


#request-types-list{
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.request-list-main li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/* #form-container has no styling at all */
```

**Description**

I've figured out that the following CSS line:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

is responsible for the fact that li blocks with too much text for one line are pushed upwards. If I remove

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

li blocks are aligned properly, but then text is displayed incorrect ( it overflows the li block, and I don't want any scrollbars to fix this ). I want the text (text of various length) to sit in the box (be wrapped if needed) and the boxes to be aligned (no box should be pushed upwards like the one in the example).

Answer (score 2):

Adding `vertical-align: middle` to list items(`li`) will help

```
.request-list-main li {
    /* ... */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/magbw149/1/

Answer (score 1):

vertical-align are always useful when deal with inline-blocks.

```
vertical-align:top;
```

I'm using top in this case, middle/bottom are available to be use as well.

Fiddle Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/6mcLfdjj/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.request-list-main li
```

In the above call you can either use `Float:left` CSS property so that it gets aligned properly along with other li's

```
.request-list-main li{

    float:left
}
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mcLfdjj/2/)